# How can I verify the owner of a signature obtained using personal_sign?

Tags: dapp-development, ethereumjs

I am validating users during login by requesting for a signature. How can I verify that the signature obtained belongs to the correct account owner?

This is how I'm obtaining the signature :

```
 const handleClick = async () => {
  const message = "verify";
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  const account = accounts[0];
  const signature = await ethereum.request({
  method: "personal_sign",
    params: [message, account],
  });
```

};

Answer (score -1):

You can verify an ECDSA Ethereum signature with PHP using the librairie [CryptoCurrencyPHP](https://github.com/tuaris/CryptoCurrencyPHP/commit/209d0c20789549dcb27a71de4f00ccc10ef806bb) and [php-keccak](https://github.com/kornrunner/php-keccak/releases/tag/1.0.3).

Here what I use for my website :

```php
// returns the Ethereum address that signed `$messageHex` from the signature {`$rHex`, `$sHex`, `$vHex`}
function ecrecover(string $messageHex, string $rHex, string $sHex, string $vHex) : string
{
    $messageGmp = gmp_init($messageHex);
    $rGmp = gmp_init($rHex);
    $sGmp = gmp_init($sHex);
    $recovery = intval($vHex, 16) - 27;

    if ($recovery !== 0 && $recovery !== 1) {

        throw new Exception('Invalid signature v value');
    }

    $publicKey = Signature::recoverPublicKey($rGmp, $sGmp, $messageGmp, $recovery);
    $publicKeyString = $publicKey["x"] . $publicKey["y"];

    $publicKeyHash = Keccak::hash(hex2bin($publicKeyString), 256);
    $recoveredAddress = substr($publicKeyHash, -20*2);  // 20 low bytes

    return "0x" . $recoveredAddress;
}
```

I can give more details if needed

Comment: since this is the only answer, a comment explaining why it is not suitable would be appreciated ;)